# Discord.js timeout Invalid communication disabled timestamp

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to build a discord bot for my server. This bot includes a `mute` command that should timeout the target user. I'm using NodeJS and added the `ms` package. The duration also gets converted into milliseconds just fine, but when I try to timeout someone for `30d` the bot crashes:

```
/root/etl-bot/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:659
        throw new DiscordAPIError(data, "code" in data ? data.code : data.error, status, method, url, requestData);
              ^

DiscordAPIError[50035]: Invalid Form Body
communication_disabled_until[INVALID_COMMUNICATION_DISABLED_TIMESTAMP]: Invalid communication disabled timestamp
    at SequentialHandler.runRequest (/root/etl-bot/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:659:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (/root/etl-bot/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:458:14)
    at async REST.request (/root/etl-bot/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:902:22)
    at async GuildMemberManager.edit (/root/etl-bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/managers/GuildMemberManager.js:325:15) {
  requestBody: {
    files: undefined,
    json: {
      communicationDisabledUntil: 1670184017237,
      communication_disabled_until: '2022-12-04T20:00:17.237Z'
    }
  },
  rawError: {
    code: 50035,
    errors: {
      communication_disabled_until: {
        _errors: [
          {
            code: 'INVALID_COMMUNICATION_DISABLED_TIMESTAMP',
            message: 'Invalid communication disabled timestamp'
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    message: 'Invalid Form Body'
  },
  code: 50035,
  status: 400,
  method: 'PATCH',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/guilds/832685267773030401/members/914947955763605554'
}
```

Didn't really try anything yet, cause I don't know what to try. Is there any limit by discord for the [GuildMember#timeout()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=timeout) function? I don't seem to find any so I'll try it here

This is the relevant code:

```
const target = message.mentions.members.first();
const time = args[2];
const reason = args.slice(3).join(' ');
const convertedTime = ms(time);
if (!convertedTime) {
  const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setColor(error)
    .setTitle(`${questionEmoji}`)
    .setDescription(`**Fehler**\nVerwende \`?mute @User Dauer Grund\``)
    .setFooter({
      text: 'Diese Nachricht löscht sich in 5 Sekunden',
    });
  await message.reply({ embeds: [embed] }).then(async (msg) => {
    setTimeout(async () => {
      msg.delete();
      message.delete();
    }, 5000);
  });
}
if (target.isCommunicationDisabled()) {
  const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setColor(error)
    .setTitle(`${questionEmoji}`)
    .setDescription(`**Fehler**\nDieser Spieler ist bereits gesperrt.`)
    .setFooter({
      text: 'Diese Nachricht löscht sich in 5 Sekunden',
    });
  await message.reply({ embeds: [embed] }).then(async (msg) => {
    setTimeout(async () => {
      msg.delete();
      message.delete();
    }, 5000);
  });
  return;
}
try {
  const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setColor(success)
    .setTitle(`${checkReply}`)
    .setDescription(
      `**Erfolg**\n**${target}** wurde wegen **${reason}** für **${time}** gesperrt.`,
    );
  message.reply({ embeds: [embed] });
  const embed2 = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setColor(primary)
    .setTitle(`${emEmoji}`)
    .setDescription(
      `**Sperre**\n**${target}** wurde von **${message.author}** wegen **${reason}** für **${time}** gesperrt.`,
    );
  teamchat.send({ embeds: [embed2] });
  target.timeout(convertedTime, reason);
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any limit by discord for the `GuildMember#timeout()` function? I don't seem to find any

Yes, there is and it's 28 days. It's strange that there is nothing about it in the discord.js documentation. However, you can find it on the Discord Developer Portal:

> `communication_disabled_until`
>
> ISO8601 timestamp
>
> when the user's timeout will expire and the user will be able to
> communicate in the guild again **(up to 28 days in the future)**, set to
> `null` to remove timeout. Will throw a 403 error if the user has the
> `ADMINISTRATOR` permission or is the owner of the guild

It means that you should check if the value of `convertedTime` is less than `2419200000` or `28 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000`

Comment: `It's strange that there is nothing about it in the discord.js documentation` - well that's because discord.js docs are really meant for showing the function usage. The API docs do have the limits, as you said. Sometimes djs docs do have the limits, but not usually